# What 90s TV show had the protagonist travel into the past using a sword?

Tags: story-identification, tv, medieval

So I was feeling a bit nostalgic. I watched a show sometime during the mid-90s, but I can't remember the name for the life of me. I will try to give some very fuzzy details:

1. I believe there was time travel involved where the protagonist would travel back in time (maybe a King Arthur setting?) with the assistance of a sword.
2. I think "sword" was in the title, but I could be completely off on this.
3. The sword was central to the plot.
4. I watched this show in the 90s on the 2nd Channel of Amman, Jordan. It would come on late night around 11PM on Thursday nights.
5. The protagonist was white, mid-40s, weak jaw, sort of flat face.
6. It was live action, and intended for adults, although there was no sex or excessive violence that I remember.

I have searched quite a bit with no luck. I may be wrong about certain aspects, but this is the best I could do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: If you can "remember exactly what the protagonist looks like", edit in a description to the question. Any detail you're sure of could be helpful for identifying it.

Comment: Also:animated or live action? Aimed at children?

Comment: “there was no sex or excessive violence that I remember” — that’s where they went wrong. They coulda been *Game of Thrones*!

Comment: Any of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Time_travel_television_series)?

Comment: No Zad, but thank you.

Comment: Nothing from the 90s with "sword" in the title at http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/uk-1990s.html ...also are you sure it involved actual time travel, or could it be something like Highlander ( http://www.amazon.com/Highlander-The-Series-Season-1/dp/B00006LPCK ), Highlander: The Raven ( http://www.amazon.com/Highlander-Raven-Complete-Paul-Johansson/dp/B00092A1J4 ) or The Immortal ( http://www.amazon.com/The-Immortal-Lorenzo-Lamas/dp/B000KGH06Q ) featuring a sword-wielding immortal main character shown in past times with flashbacks?

Comment: YES.YES. YES!!!! It wasn't any of the show you mentioned, but that first link had the name of the show: "The Wanderer". So I was off about the sword being central... Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Cool, according to http://www.the-medium-is-not-enough.com/2013/05/nostalgia_corner_the_wanderer_1994.php there hasn't been a DVD release but you can at least find some clips there.

Comment: Since you've located the show, you should make it an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 6):

The Name of the show is: "[The Wanderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wanderer_(1994_TV_series))".

> Shy multi-millionaire businessman Adam ("the Wanderer" of the show's
>   title) and his wicked twin brother Zachary (both played by Bryan
>   Brown) are two former knights from the late Tenth Century, both of
>   whom have been born again in the late Twentieth Century. Zachary is
>   after a complicated revenge on Adam, who killed him in the year A.D.
>   1000, but much more is at stake than mere vengeance. As the turn of
>   the Third Millennium approaches, people grow more superstitious, and
>   Zachary plans to use this for his own purpose. He needs his brother
>   dead and seen by witnesses so he can pose as Adam resurrected.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could describe what about the show matches up with the OP's recalled details.

Comment: @phantom42 This is the OP.

Comment: @MrLister Ah, yes. It'd still be helpful though. Especially since the comments indicate that the memories were slightly off regarding the sword at the very least.